# Two-way binding between an angular 2 component and service using Observable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs5

I've been trying to make a simple relation between an angular 2 component and service, but I can't figure it out how to do so using Observable.

My component `HeroViewerComponent` subscribes to the router parameter `id` and passes it to a service `HeroService` to get `Hero` when the service get it from the server. `HeroService` has a method called `getHeroSubscription` that takes an `Observable<number>` as a parameter and return `Observable<Hero>`. But it doesn't work.

Here is my `HeroViewerComponent` in `hero-viewer.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Observer } from "rxjs/Observer";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

import { HeroService } from "./hero.service";
import { Hero } from "./hero";

@Component({
    providers: [HeroService]
})
export class HeroViewerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private routeParamsSubscription:Subscription;

    // to the service
    private routeParamsObservable:Observable<number>;

    // the subscriber of the route ID param
    private routeParamsObserver:Observer<number>;

    // from the service
    private heroSubscription:Subscription;

    // the current hero
    hero:Hero;

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private heroService:HeroService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeParamsObservable = new Observable<number>((observer:Observer<number>) => this.routeParamsObserver = observer);

        this.heroSubscription = this.heroService
            .getHeroSubscription(this.routeParamsObservable)
            .subscribe(
                hero => this.hero = hero,
                error => console.warn(error)
            );

        this.routeParamsSubscription = this.route
            .params
            .subscribe(
                params => this.routeParamsObserver.next( +params["id"] ),
                error => console.warn(error)
            );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeParamsSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.heroSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.routeParamsObserver.complete();
    }
}
```

Here is my `HeroService` in `hero.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Observer } from "rxjs/Observer";
import "rxjs/add/operator/merge";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";

import { Hero } from "./hero";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    constructor(private http:Http) {}

    getHeroSubscription(heroIdObservable:Observable<number>):Observable<Hero> {
        let heroObserver:Observer<Hero>;
        let heroObservable = new Observable<Hero>((observer:Observer<Hero>) => {
            heroObserver = observer;
        });

        let heroIdSubscription = heroIdObservable.subscribe(
            heroId => {
                const tmp = this.http
                    .get("api/heroes/" + heroId)
                    .map((response:Response) => response.json().data)
                    .catch((response:any) => {
                        if (response instanceof Response) {
                            return Observable.throw(response.json().error);
                        }
                        return Observable.throw(response);
                    });
                heroObservable.merge(tmp);
            },
            error => console.warn(error),
            () => {
                heroIdSubscription.unsubscribe();
                heroObserver.complete();
            }
        );

        return heroObservable;
    }
}
```

And here is my `Hero` in `hero.ts`:

```
export class Hero {public id: number;}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you subscribing to a route parameter? I'm not sure I understood your purpose here.

Comment: Becase I bind `HeroViewerComponent` to a route `heroes/:id` so that the parameter can be changed without destroying the component. For example, I am on the route `heroes/10043` and `HeroViewerComponent` renderers the hero with ID `10043`. When I move on (ie on the route `heroes/874`), the component just renderers a new hero.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the possible problem, that `heroObservable.merge(tmp)` doesn't mutate `heroObservable`, but returns new observable, which is lost in your code.

Try to store it in any variable and return for `getHeroSubscription` method instead of just `return heroObservable`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to solve the problem. Is there a way to mutate `heroObservable` ("put" one `Observable` inside the other)?

Comment: Only using static methods from Observable, like `zip` or `forkJoin`  - you can try to find smth in examples, like https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md